# Data export for CSV file --> Error message PLS-00201: ID 'COL_LIST'

Tags: oracle, export

I am still new to SQL, but I would like to create a procedure that exports a complete table as CSV. My current SQL code looks like this (Oracle SQL Developer):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBPW_TEST (
   p_directory VARCHAR2,
   p_tabname   VARCHAR2,
   p_schema    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT USER)
IS
    tab_refcur        SYS_REFCURSOR;
    l_header          VARCHAR2(4000);
    l_zeile           VARCHAR2(4000);
    l_col_list        VARCHAR2(4000);
    l_stmt            VARCHAR2(4000);
    l_file            UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
 BEGIN
    l_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(
        location  => UPPER(p_directory),
        filename  => p_tabname||'_'||TO_CHAR(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd-hh24-mi')||'.csv',
        open_mode => 'w',
     max_linesize => 32767);
  -- Zusammenstellung der Spaltenliste für die Überschriften-Zeile
    l_header := col_list(
            p_tabname => p_tabname,
             p_schema => p_schema,
              p_delim => ';');
  -- Die Überschriften werden in die Datei geschrieben
     UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(l_file, l_header);
  -- Zusammenstellung der Spaltenliste für den Select
     l_col_list := col_list(
             p_tabname => p_tabname,
              p_schema => p_schema ,
               p_delim => q'[||';'||]', -- alternativ '||'';''||'
                p_trim => 1);
     l_stmt   := 'SELECT '||l_col_list||' FROM '||p_schema||'.'||p_tabname;
  -- Über den Ref Cursor werden die Spalteninhalte jeder Zeile
  -- als Strings aneinandergehängt
     OPEN tab_refcur FOR l_stmt;
     LOOP
  -- und in die Variable eingelesen
       FETCH tab_refcur INTO l_zeile;
       EXIT WHEN tab_refcur%NOTFOUND;
       -- mit der Prozedur PUT_LINE wird Zeile für Zeile geschrieben
     UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(l_file, l_zeile);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE tab_refcur;
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(l_file);
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   -- hier sollte natürlich eine vernünftige Fehleraufzeichnung passieren
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(l_file);
   RAISE;
END DBPW_TEST;
```

Unfortunately I get the Error message PLS-00201: ID 'COL_LIST'. It is unclear to me how or if I have to define this.

Can someone give me a hint/ the solution?

Many greetings

I have tried online to find a solution and adjust the script, but unfortunately without success

Comment: You're doing `l_header := col_list(...);` - so is that a function you have defined, maybe in a package or another schema? Or did you copy this code from somewhere and not take everything related to it, perhaps? (Maybe you're looking for [this](https://www.muniqsoft-training.de/oracle/muso_training/r/schulung/tipp-anzeige?p1001_tippauswahl=484&p1001_cs=3967454836&request=Export_von_Tabellen_als_CSV-Files_mit_UTL_File)? Looks like you've copied/changed the procedure, but not the function it has on the same page?)

Comment: ok, now i get it. thanks for you help. :-)